Interactive animation in Flutter
what I'm looking for is the best approach in making an animated Container (simple scale animation) that is controlled by the use onLongPress touch.
GetsureDetector has methods to detect the user gestures for tap and hold and then release.
I succesfully managed to start an animation on tap and hold but after that I don't know how to have the animation in sync with the user holding time and stop it when he release the finger from the screen.
I did search around and most animations get started and then forgot, they continue with their lifecycle autonomously till the end. Is AnimationController the right approach for the task? I cannot find examples of what I mean with it so I'm not sure.
I try to use a Timer but the animation continues for a while after the user release his tap action.
Some relevant code below
 GestureDetector(
      
      onLongPress: () {
        timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), (timer) {
          setState(() => _pileColor = Colors.white70);
          setState(() {
            _pileHeigh += 50;
            _pileWidth += 50;
          });
        });
      },
      onLongPressEnd: (details) => {
            
            timer?.cancel(),
           
          },
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child: Column(children: [
                  Center(
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                      height: _pileHeigh,
                      width: _pileWidth,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: _pileColor, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                      curve: Curves.linear,
                    ),
                  )
                ]))
              ])))


yes AnimationController is a right way, check it's animateWith method that can start theoretically infinite animation (by using GravitySimulation for example)
